# Has TeX Live stopped signing the public repository?

Tags: texlive, repositories, security, texlive-2017, tlmgr

Recently it appears to me that the TeX Live repository is no longer signed with the release PGP key.  When using the `tlmgr update` command, it always reports `tlmgr: package repository [mirrored repo url] (not verified: not signed)`

Is this a temporary (or local) issue or a permanent change in the infrastructure?

Comment: this is temporary, an unintended error.  there was a note with an explanation just a short while ago on the tex-live list.

Comment: Thank you, @barbarabeeton. I hope a resolution is coming soon.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Do you know why it bothers checking the signature when it goes ahead and installs regardless? I've never understood the point.

Comment: @cfr -- all i know is what was reported on the tex-live list, and i don't remember the details, but the list archives, on the tug.org website, are open.  i may be mistaken, but i think that if the signature check fails, it should stop the installation, and that's what the fix will be.

Comment: @cfr, it doesn't "[go] ahead and installs regardless" if you use the option `--require-verification` or `require-verification = 1` in the config file.

Comment: @CongMa By default, it checks but ignores a failure.

Comment: @barbarabeeton As far as I understand it, that's only true if you change the default. The default is to check, but carry on regardless, and I've never seen the point. It just suggests a level of security is there which is simply illusory.

Comment: @cfr I guess that it is often because if users do not have the right tolls installed to verify the download, tl would be very complicated to install for many users. (having to install first tl and then figuring out where to get go or what ever is used). Last time I checked it will use pgp to verify if present, but go forth if it is not present.

Comment: a message came through the tex-live list at about 03:45 eastern u.s. time confirming that the problem has been fixed.

Comment: @CongMa Thanks for the tip. I have to say that this is most unobvious, especially since there is no config file by default. (I know it is in the manual page, but a default config file with comments is a common user-friendly provision.) Also, it is not set up so that it will persist for a new version of TL, which is annoying. I don't like to have to remember to make things secure. I'd rather have to remember to relax the restrictions.

Comment: @daleif But it goes ahead, as I understand it, even if the tools are available and verification fails. I understand going ahead if the system doesn't have the tools. (That's debatable, but certainly arguably the right default.) But I don't understand going ahead if verification positively fails, so to speak. It seems to me that, in this case, it is better to only perform the verification if specifically requested as a failure is useless if it doesn't halt further action.

Comment: @cfr but if the user has not explicitly  enabled required verification explicitly, they do not know what that failure is.... then I see why it just ignores it.

Comment: @daleif You could say the same about all package managers. The norm is to be secure by default and require users to explicitly approve unsafe operations. Here, the default is to allow insecure operations. Plus, in any case, why bother verifying, if you're going to carry on anyway? The 'verified' messages just provides a false sense of security. It doesn't even *ask* whether to continue ....

Comment: @cfr take it up with the texlive people, it is better descussed there than here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by Barbara, this was a temporary error, and since yesterday the files are signed again. This was due to the required expiry extension of the signing sub key.

We are taking/have taken the following measures:

- (already done) `tlmgr` will require the *main* repository to be signed, and will refuse working if the main repository isn't. This change is in `tlcritical` and will be pushed out after testing.
- (in progress) make sure that a signing error on the build server will prohibit the push-out to the CTAN servers

Concerning the comments about security by default: We thought about requiring signature in case GPG is installed, but initial testing brought a huge opposition against this move.  Now that verification was running smoothly for one year we feel reasonably save to require at least a signed main repository.

Concerning sub-repositories we are not decided by now: First of all we cannot and don't want all repositories to be signed, this should be optional. The question is what to do with signed repositories if the user has not imported the public key to allow for verification. At the moment we accept such repositories, in the same spirit as Debian does.

Hope that clarifies the situation.